# How get value from database ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How get items from table ? I want get value from **question** column, using condition.

```
@result = Customers.where(:name => session[:username], :email => session[:useremail])
```

Now, I can get value from any column ? like this: @result.column_from_customers_table   , right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake for beginners.  The code you have returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and doesn't actually connect to your db yet.  In order to get a record you have to loop through each one of the results or call `.first` on it in order to get the first matching result

```
# returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object
@results = Customers.where(:name => session[:username], :email => session[:useremail])

# returns the first matching record
@object = @results.first

# then you can call the column names on @object
@object.name
@object.email

# looping through the results
@results.each do |object|
  puts object.name
  puts object.email
end
```